# Gradient of Unstructured grid filter in paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview

There used to be a quite useful filter in Paraview called **GradinetOfUnstructuredGrid**. We could efficiently and effectively calculate the divergence, curl and vorticity of vector field quite easily. For some reasons, they removed this feature in the latest version.

Is there any other way to do the same in ParaView now? Or is there any way to re-install the much better older version?

Edit :
The filter called **GradientOfUnstructuredDataset** is not similar. For instance, it will not give us Gradient, Curl and Vorticity.

When we apply this filter we get a set of arrays confusingly named from 0- 9, for my uses and purposes this filter is totally useless.

I'm using V 5.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still here and called `GradientOfUnstructuredDataSet`.

Tested in the 5.9.0 RC3 downloaded from the [website](https://www.paraview.org/download/)  (where you can also download previous versions)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. But this is not same as the filter which I mentioned. This was there even before, I'm talking about the filter GradientOfUnstructuredGrid.

Comment: I do not see GradientOfUnstructuredGrid in pv 5.8.0 from the website, nor in code source. Do you use plugins ? Did you check advanced properties of the GradientOfUnstructuredDataSet ?

Comment: Hi, I did not use any plug-ins, I can't remember which verso I was using before. I only remember the name of the filter.

Comment: I have tried looking in all options, But I can't find a way to calculate the divergence with this filter.

Comment: Divergence is an [advanced property](https://docs.paraview.org/en/v5.8/ReferenceManual/propertiesPanel.html#search-box) of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. The option is still there, just difficult to find.

(1) You can choose the **GradientOfUnstructuredDataset** filter by going to the filters tool bar.
(2) Then select the vector field of which you want to compute the divergence.
(3) Then click on the Settings icon ( it is right under the properties panel ),
the advanced properties tab will pp open. You can choose to calculate divergence, curl and vorticity from there.